# Proslife PS4 Controller Bluetooth Not Working On Windows 10

Tags: steam, ps4, controllers, windows

My Proslife controller works in-game over USB but not via Bluetooth. It is connected to the PC via Bluetooth and the input test works when running JOY.CPL, it even works on the controller menu in Steam settings. But in-game, the controller is not detected. It also doesn't seem to be detected by DS4Windows.

Comment: Really, I feel like steam detects controllers way better when in Big Screen Mode. So maybe try that?

Answer (score 0):

> But in-game, the controller is not detected.

You are probably trying to use a game that only supports XInput devices (aka only Xbox 360/One/Series controllers).

> It also doesn't seem to be detected by DS4Windows.

I don't see any references to Proslife in the [list of known devices on the DS4Windows repo](https://github.com/Ryochan7/DS4Windows/blob/jay/DS4Windows/DS4Library/DS4Devices.cs#L126). You should probably open an issue and give out information so the developers can add support for it.

Comment: Thanks. But the thing is, these controllers are designed so that the computer thinks it IS an Xbox controller (which is why it works via the USB cable). So why is it that when I switch to bluetooth the game no longer recognises it?

Comment: What device name appears in JOY.CPL?

Comment: @Reason - I'd hazard a guess that the Bluetooth connection requires different drivers to operate when compared to USB. You'll also need to ensure the device paired correctly